# Extract md5 hash from pem.cert using Ansible

Tags: openssl, ansible

Want to extract `md5` hash from `crt.pem` using ansible, there are some nice examples in the [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/openssl_certificate_module.html) but I'm still not sure can I extract it, at least docs are not covering that part.

Simple example was to try manually, like this:

```
- name: Extract extra MD5 hash from dab_certs
  command: openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint -md5 -inform pem -in path="{{ certs_path }}/FILE.crt.pem"
```

but I have `No such file or directory` for a given path, so what is the proper way of doing it with Ansible?

Comment: Remove the `path=`.

Comment: @clockworknet yup, if you could answer so I can up upvote, removing `path=` solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `path=` in front of the variable that holds the path to your cert. That is certainly not valid in the `openssl` command, so I am guessing there is an expectation that Ansible needs this, which is not the case.

Removing `path=` will clear up the error.